What aircraft has the propeller with the highest blade count?
Among all known propeller (unducted) aircraft, which one has the highest number of blades?
Experimental aircraft also count.

The Antonov An-70 is powered by 4 Progress D-27 "propfans", or more technically contra-rotating turboprops, each of which has 14 blades: 8 on the front propeller, 6 on the aft one.
That at 56 blades total puts it ahead of any other modern propeller aircraft. It also has the most blades per engine, at 8+6, while the rest top out at 8.

The Dornier Do-X is an honorable mention at 12 engines with 4-bladed props, also in a contra-rotating configuration, with 48 blades total.
Some Safran's open rotor mockups have shown as many as 12+12 blades per engine, but they're yet to fly, and since 2 engines is the likely maximum for new commercial aircraft, that's still only going to be 48 total.


This raises the question of whether a non-rotating blade counts or not.  These are/will be used to make the airflow behind the moving blades straighter rather than helical.  In straightening the airflow they produce additional thrust so it’s arguable that they are collectively a propeller.

Safrans wacky inflatable turbo prop ?

Do we count turbofans or only unducted props? On a technical level, the blades of a turbofan are just a specific kind of ducted prop and regularly have 20+ blades.

@DarthPseudonym Based on the question, which speaks of propeller aircraft, I would definitely exclude turbofans. But "open rotors" and "propfans" are types of propellers, even if they use other terms to market their more advanced nature. Just like a macbook is still a laptop.

it is limited to unducted only

@Therac thanks for all the data. I want to limit the question to individual props. So that means the Antonov only has 8 blades.

Obviously, things can get a little weird...

@Gabe 8 is the highest any production airplane has anyway. Any more has only been seen in so-far-experimental open rotor designs.

Very interesting that the An-70 has a different number of blades on each propeller.  I suppose the engineering, physics, and aerodynamic testing all played a part in deciding that.

@pr1268 Of course. The two propellers work in very different aero conditions, with high load on the back propeller. To keep the gearbox light, it needs to balance the torque. Also, different blade counts reduce the "chop" sound from blade interaction.

German company MT-Propeller seems to have built and flight-tested 9- and 11-bladed propellers.


(photos from their site)
